# Changes to css doesnt appear live

Tags: css, prestashop

I saw similar theme, but none of the solutions mentioned there worked out.
I updated my global.css of prestashop, but changes doesn't go live.. Why ? 
Though, you can see croosed out changes when inspecting element. (look img)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFYQA.png) What's the problem ?

Comment: Sorry to ask but, did you flush your cache i backoffice and flush your cache in Web Browser ?

Comment: Those crossed out changes and current rules in effect link to the files they are defined as so might be worth investigating whats going on. It looks like there's some minifying, merging and caching going on there so you may need to clear caches.

Answer (score 3):

Crossed out css rules are the result of the rule being overridden by another rule of higher precedence.  In your case, the rules appear to have the same specificity in their selector, therefore we can conclude that the overriding rule must have been redeclared after the rule you wanted.

Look for a place in your code where the css might be included twice.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Arrison is right, you have to merge the rules together. 
But, if you cannot merge the two properties for `#article-heading`, you can add the key `body` before `#article-heading`. That way the properties of `body #article-heading` will have the higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

in Advanced Preferences > Performance > CCC (COMBINE, COMPRESS AND CACHE), have you tried disabling " Smart Cache for Css"?

From your screenshot I can see that there is a minified CSS file (letter_and_numbers.css). If your code is in global.css when you inspect it, it should be visible the global.css file.

If you already disabled the "smart Cache for CSS" in the advanced parameters and it's still not working maybe you are using a service like Cloudflare or similar?

Cloudflare for example has a built-in option for caching and minifying CSS so even if you turn it off in Prestashop, you will also need to disable it there.